# Array size and Pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
    int a[],i,lim,sum=0;
    printf("Enter the limit of the array: ");
    scanf("%d",&lim);
    printf("Enter the values: ");
    for(i=0;i<lim;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    int *p;
    for(p=&a[0];p<lim;p++)
    {
        sum=sum+*p;
    }
    printf("Sum= %d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

While running the code I'm getting the following error
**..\src\Test6.c: In function 'main':

..\src\Test6.c:5:6: error: array size missing in 'a'

..\src\Test6.c:14:15: warning: comparison between pointer and integer**
Please help me understand why I've to declare the array size when I have no issues doing the same without pointers.
Or please help me understand what change should I make to rectify the error:)

Comment: arrays are not pointers, pointers are not arrays. You might like to read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: `p<lim`: you are comparing a pointer to an int. You could write `p<&a[lim]`

Comment: What do you mean by " I have no issues doing the same without pointers"? You always need to declare the array size, regardless of whether you later use pointers.

Comment: Closed this as a dup. The accepted answer gives a deep explanation on the difference between arrays and pointers.

Comment: You could really use your warning and errors. When declaring arrays, you must specify its size or you could use `VLAs` if your compiler supports `c99 or c11` or use a dynamic array. Then for the second warning, read the comment by @PaulOgilvie

Answer (score 0):

declare the size too when declaring the array.

eg.

```
int a[100000];
```

here you can put atmost 100000 elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

your loop

> ```
>    for(p=&a[0];p<lim;p++)
>    {
>        sum=sum+*p;
>    }
> ```

should be written as

```
for (p = &a[0]; p < &a[lim]; p++)
{
    sum += *p;
}
```

or, more usually using index,

```
for (int index = 0; index < limit; index++)
{
    sum += a[index];
}
```